# Building a string of Python Code in PyInstaller?

Tags: python, exe, py2exe, pyinstaller

I understand how we can package an .exe by pointing PyInstaller to a file. Such like:

```
c:\Python25\python c:\Users\Mike\Desktop\pyinstaller-1.4\Makespec.py -F -w sampleApp.py
```

However is there a way to create an .exe with only a string [and not a file]? Such as:

```
string="""
print "Hello world"

"""

buildApplication(string) #Function Does not exist
```

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate a bit more on what is your use case for this?

Comment: I am making an software creator and I would not like people to see the source files on their hard drive.

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to create a temporary `.py` file with the generated source code and feed that to PyInstaller.

Comment: I am doing that now however I do not want to risk allowing the user to see the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, I am afraid you won't be able to work around the need to create a temporary file with any of the existing standalone executable creation tools (*py2exe*, *PyInstaller* and *cxFreeze*).

What I see as the most viable solution is a bit of security through obscurity, combining the following two techniques:

1. Create a byte-code compiled file (`.pyc`) directly, instead of the plaintext `.py` file, from the generated code string, using the `__builtin__.compile` function (you can find on the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/py_compile.py#l71) of the [py_compile](http://docs.python.org/library/py_compile.html) module how to achieve this. A byte-compiled file will be significantly less useful to prying eyes than the source file.
2. A temporary file with an obscure name and location created using the [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) module. This file will be relatively short lived, but obviously, a sufficiently determined user will be able to find it and copy it while it existes to be consumed by the executable creation tool.